# using BeautifulSoup find paragraphs and and combine paragraphs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape the main body of multiple news articles. I find the main body of each news article is organized in this way:

```
<div class="article-body resizeFont">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    <p style="font-size: 100%;">
    <p style="font-size: 100%;">
    <p style="font-size: 100%;">
    ....
```

I wrote this code to first scrape all the paragraphs, and then put paragraphs into each article, then put every article into the list "myarticle".

```
            for pagelink in pagelinks:
                #get page text
                page = requests.get(pagelink)
                #parse with BeautifulSoup
                soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
                containerr = soup.find("div", class_=['entry-content', 'entry-content-read-more'])
                articletext = containerr.find_all('p')
                thearticle = [] # clear from the previous loop
                paragraphtext = [] # clear from the previous loop
                for paragraph in articletext:
                    text = paragraph.get_text()
                    paragraphtext.append(text)
                # put paragraphs into a single article, and put all the articles into a list
                myarticle.append(thearticle.append(paragraphtext))
                print(myarticle)
```

The output is wrong, it returns this

```
[None]
[None, None]
[None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I wonder which step is wrong with my code? (if needed, one of the article I'm scraping is https://www.startribune.com/asian-stocks-mixed-amid-china-tension-with-us-australia/570651732/?refresh=true)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: ```myarticle.append(thearticle.append(paragraphtext))``` typo in there, append does not return any value instead return's ```None```

Comment: change to ```thearticle.append(paragraphtext)```, ```myarticle.extend(thearticle)```